# displaying pdf using google docs viewer in fancybox

Tags: fancybox, google-docs

I have this working successfully, however there are a number of options which are automatically displayed in the iframe in the top right corner, such as, previous page, next page, zoom in, zoom out and I was just wondering if there was a way to customise these? Thanks